# fetch data between min and max price from mongodb using node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to fetch data between min and max price from property model

e.g.if user inputs min and max price then the number of properties between that min and max price will show

i have indexed the $text in for type and tags value

I am new to mongodb..
appreciate the help.
thankyou

here is my controller code

```
searchProperty = async (req, res) => {
const property = await Property
// first find the property that matches
.find({
    $text: {
        $search: req.query.q
    }
}, {
    score: { $meta: 'textScore' }
})
// then sort them
.sort({
    score: { $meta: 'textScore' }
})
// limit to only 5 result
//.limit(5)
res.json(property); };
```

here is my model

```
const propertySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: 'Please enter your name!'
},
status: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Please enter the status!'
},
type: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Please enter your type!'
},
rooms: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Please enter your no of Rooms!'
},
old: String,
bedrooms: String,
bathrooms: String,
phone: Number,
title: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: 'Please enter your property title!'
},
price: {
    type: Number,
    required: 'Please enter your Price!'
},
area: Number,
description: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: 'Please enter your description!'
},
zipcode: Number,
slug: String,
tags: [String],
created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
},
location: {
    type: {
        type: String,
        default: 'Point'
    },
    coordinates: [{
        type: Number,
        required: 'Please enter the Coordinates!'
    }],
    address: {
        type: String,
        required: 'Please enter the Address!'
    }
},
author: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    reuqired: 'You must supply an author'
} });
   // Define our indexes
   propertySchema.index({
    type: 'text',
    tags: 'text'
  });
```

here is my route

```
router.get('/api/v1/search', searchProperty);
```

Comment: why are you limiting your results, if you want to get the results for min and max? I suggest you use the aggregation with $match including $text as first stage and then again use a $match with $gte and $lte on the price. Refer below - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/text-search-in-aggregation/

Comment: i have commented out that limit in the code and thanks for the tip @Avij

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$gte` and `$lte` for this.

```
db.properties.find({price: { $gte: 1, $lte: 1000 } } );
```

This will fetch the properties with the price between 1 and 1000.

Comment: god it was easy.. 1 line code.. thats all you need. thank you for the help

Comment: @RahulGupta Can you accept the answer if it helped you?